# Finding a large prime in C++: where does my integer overflow?

Tags: c++, primes, integer-overflow

I wrote an implementation of the [Sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin)  in C++ to calculate large primes. It works perfectly fine for finding up to the 10^8th prime, but when trying to find the 10^9th prime number, I get an incorrect result.

It looks like I'm dealing with an integer overflow, but I can't figure out how this is possible. I'm using `uint64_t` everywhere, and the desired result ([22801763489](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000000000th%20prime)) lies between 2^34 and 2^35.

The result I'm getting is `1326927009`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
uint64_t getPrimesAtkin(uint64_t Nn)
{
    (...)
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (int a = 7; a < 10; a += 2)
    {
        clock_t begin = clock();
        uint64_t prime = getPrimesAtkin(pow(10,a));
        clock_t end = clock();
        printf("p(10^%d)=%12d t=%4.3f\n",a,prime, double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using floating-point functions (`log()`, `floor()`, etc.) doesn't seem like a terribly good idea.

Comment: I don't know C++ so this may be nonsense, but is there a limit on the size of a vector? When you initialize sieve, even though N+1 fits in a uint64_t, perhaps the maximum size of the vector is too small to hold that many booleans.

Comment: `printf("p(10^%d)=%12d...`  I don't think `%12d` will make `printf` print a 64 bit integer correctly. Try using `cout`.

Comment: Continuing what @user448810 said, try to ensure 64-bit size_t (meaning vector will support allocating the memory you need) by using appropriate compiler flag. For g++ add `-mcmodel=large`

Comment: @user448810: when using dynamic allocation the max size is dependent on the cpu/compiler/etc. There is no fixed max size for a vector like there is for an array in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not read all of your code carefully, but this line alone can explain your problem:

```
printf("p(10^%d)=%12d t=%4.3f\n",a,prime, double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Here you pass the 64 bit prime to the `printf()` function using the format `"%12d"`. This format expects an argument of type `int`, regardless of the number of digits that are used for output. To print a `long long` (guaranteed to be at least 64 bits), use the `"ll"` modifier (`"%12lld"`) and pass the prime with a cast `(long long)prime`.